# python sqlite3 insert command

Tags: python, insert, sqlite

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm creating a table called General:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbLocation)
    c = conn.cursor()        
    sql = "create table if not exists General (id integer NOT NULL,current char[20] NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))"
    c.execute(sql)
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

I'm then using max(id) to see if the table is empty. If it is, I create a table called Current1 and insert a row in General (id, 'Current1'). id is autoincrementing integer:

```
    self.currentDB = "Current1"
    self.currentDBID = "1"
    #create the table
    sql = "create table %s (id integer NOT NULL,key char[90] NOT NULL,value float NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))" % (str(self.currentDB))
    c.execute(sql)
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbLocation)
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "insert into General(current) values('%s')" % (str(self.currentDB))
    print "sql = %s" % (str(sql)) ---> *sql = insert into General(current) values('Current1')*
    c.execute(sql)
    print "executed insert Current"
    c.execute ("select max(id) from General")
    temp = c.next()[0]
    print "temp = %s" % (str(temp)) ---> *temp = 1*
    c.close()
    conn.close()
```

The problem is that if I open the database, I do not find any rows in the General table. Current1 table is being created, but the insert statement into General does not seem to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit the changes before closing the connection:

```
conn.commit()
```

check the example in the docs : http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Just found the answer on another page before I refreshed this one and found your answers. You are right, I also tried committing with variable c but didn't work...it has to be on conn. Thanks a lot :) Will mark yours as the right answer since yours is the first one, even though @Maxime Lorant is right too!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the connection as a context manager: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed

Example:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('current')
with conn:
    conn.execute("create table if not exists General (id integer NOT NULL,current char[20] NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))")
    conn.execute("insert into General(current) values('{0}')".format("some data"))

with conn:
    q = conn.execute("select max(id) from General")
q.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit changes in the database with

```
conn.commit()
```

This will write on the disk changes you made in your database. If you close your database without doing it, you lost your modification (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE)